# How to add constraints programatically to place a label at the left bottom of the screen?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to place a label at the bottom left of the screen: So I added the following code:

```
    UILabel *versionLabel = [UILabel new];
  versionLabel.text = @"some text";
  versionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  versionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
  [self.view addSubview:versionLabel];
    [versionLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(versionLabel);


    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-3-[versionLabel]"
                               options:0
                               metrics:nil
                               views:views]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[versionLabel]-3-|"
                               options:0
                               metrics:nil
                               views:views]];
```

My issue is that the label ends up at the top left always. No way to move it at the bottom when I add constraints.

Comment: You don't need to set the frame if you're going to use constraints (so use UILabel *label1= [UILabel new]). You also don't need sizeToFit, and I don't know what this line is supposed to be doing: [self.view label1]? I assume that's a typo (you should copy and paste your actual code, don't type it in).

Comment: Hi rdelmar, Sorry that error was caused when I edited my copy pasted code. I did copy paste my code, but was editing my actual variable names. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Try changing your VFL to `V:[label1]-3-|`, it may work.

Comment: no Luck still on top left

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the UITableViewController in a UIViewController, you can layout the label and table view as you see fit.

```
#import "WrappingViewController.h"
#import "YourCustomTableViewController.h"

@implementation WrappingViewController {
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // I instantiate this manually, but you could use an outlet from interface builder
    UITableViewController *tableViewController = [YourCustomTableViewController new];
    [self addChildViewController:tableViewController];

    UIView *tableView = tableViewController.view;

    UILabel *label1 = [UILabel new];
    label1.text = @"Some text";
    label1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];

    label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
    [self.view addSubview:label1];

    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(tableView, label1);

    [self.view addConstraints:
        [NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[tableView]|" // make the tableview take the whole width
            options:0
            metrics:nil
            views:views]
    ];

    [self.view addConstraints:
        [NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-3-[label1]" // attach the label 3 pixels from the left
            options:0
            metrics:nil
            views:views]
    ];

    [self.view addConstraints:
        [NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tableView]-[label1]-3-|" // attach tableview to top, then space, then label, 3px, then bottom
            options:0
            metrics:nil
            views:views]
    ];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I used the above code but my label goes to the top left:

Comment: Are you adding the label to a subview within another view (e.g. a View within a View Controller's View). If so then maybe the label is aligned with the bottom of the view, but the view is sized to fit round the label?

Comment: It is a subclass of table view controller. And I added the above code to its view Didload method.Does that answer the question?

Comment: It is relevant that your view controller is a table view controller, because a UITableViewController's view is a UITableView set to use all the available space.

You could add your label and have it "float" on top of the table view, but what I would be inclined to do is have your screen be made of a UIViewController that wraps the UITableViewController as a sub view controller. The UIViewController could then add the UITableViewController's UITableView and your label as a subview, then you can layout as you see fit. I will update my answer to reflect this approach.